# Объявление компонента для последующего вызова с аргументами для v-model

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, компоненты

Изучаю использование директивы `v-model`. В связи с существованием возможности использования директивы v-model с аргументами компонента и статьей [Изменения в работе v-model](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/migration/v-model.html#%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) возник вопрос:

1. **как объявить** (**указать export**) дочерний компонент, чтобы обеспечить его двустороннее связывание, если его вызов имеет вид  `<ChildComponent v-model:title="pageTitle" />`?

В документации приведен только пример для v-model без аргументов

```
 <ChildComponent v-model="pageTitle" />


// ChildComponent.vue

export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: String // раньше было `value: String`
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  methods: {
    changePageTitle(title) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', title) // раньше было `this.$emit('input', title)`
    }
  }
}
```

2. Что должно быть в template ChildComponent-а (например, если ChildComponent является input-ом)?

Comment: https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/component-custom-events.html#%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-v-model

Comment: по твоей же ссылке есть пример с аргументами: https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/migration/v-model.html#%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-v-model

Answer (score 0):

По твоей [ссылке](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/migration/v-model.html#%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) приведен пример с аргументами тоже

Единственное отличие от кода без аргументов, а том, что меняется имя свойства на имя аргумента и название события.

Без аргументов имя свойства `modelValue` с аргументом - то что указано в аргументе:

```
<ChildComponent v-model:title="pageTitle" />
```

в данном случае аргументом является `:title`, соответсвенно компонент раскрывается как

```
<ChildComponent :title="pageTitle" @update:title="pageTitle = $event" />
```

В коде

```
export default {
  props: {
    title: String // раньше было `value: String`
  },
  emits: ['update:title'],
  methods: {
    changePageTitle(title) {
      this.$emit('update:title', title) // раньше было `this.$emit('input', title)`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: а в template ChildComponent-а что должно быть?

Comment: я обновил вопрос.

Comment: @hpwebsearch, то что ты хочешь. Это обычный шаблон в котором ты можешь использовать объявленные свойства и методы

Comment: конкретно для ChildComponent-а, который является input-ом и вызывается с помощью команды <ChildComponent v-model:title="pageTitle" /> как будет выглядеть template?

Comment: @hpwebsearch, как ты напишешь template так он и будет выглядеть

Comment: как будет выглядеть template компонента - input-а, который имеет атрибут title и принимает событие updateTitle? Мне это очень нужно.

Comment: @hpwebsearch, у инпута нет события `updateTitle`. Поэтому на твой вопрос невозможно ответить